# How to download an embedded swf?

Tags: javascript, flash

I am viewing an ebook on a site through the VPN connection of the library of my university. The ebook is being displayed via Adobe Flash and I cannot save or download the ebook. I want to store the swf file locally which is embedded on this site. The script looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var flashvars = {};
if (swfobject.getQueryParamValue("ean")) {
  flashvars.ebook_loc = "/fileadmin/preselect/content/campus";
  flashvars.ean = "9783593411743";
  flashvars.INITIAL_PAGE = "0";
  flashvars.pdY= "";
  flashvars.pdX= "";
  flashvars.aC= "25";
  flashvars.cT= "© 2012 by PRESELECT.media";
  flashvars.hT = "Hilfe";
  flashvars.hTl = "index.php?id=fp_help";
  flashvars.sPT = "Aktuelle Seite drucken";
  flashvars.mPT = "Aktuelle und folgende 9 Seiten drucken";
  flashvars.cpT = "Zitat kopieren";
  flashvars.stamp = "Lizensiert für KIT Karlsruhe. 2012-07-29";
  flashvars.cL = "Unterkapitel ausblenden";
  flashvars.cLK = encodeURIComponent('index.php?id=bib_view&ean=9783593411743&toc=zu');
}
var params = {};
var attributes = {
  id: "flash",
  name: "flash",
  scale:"noscale"
};

if (screen.width > 1280) {
      var hoehe = "1250";
      var breite = "930";
    } 
else if(screen.width > 1024)
     {
      var hoehe = "1150";
      var breite = "850";
    } 
    else {
      var hoehe = "850";
      var breite = "640";
    }

swfobject.embedSWF(flashvars.ebook_loc+"/holder_040212.swf", "swf", breite, hoehe, "8.0.0",flashvars.ebook_loc+"/expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
</script>
```

Is there any software tool which does this? Thanks for your time!

Comment: what's wrong with just trying to get the file from it's location at "/fileadmin/preselect/content/campus/holder_040212.swf"?

Comment: I get a 44 KB SWF File which I can't open in the stand-alone flash player or in a browser.

Comment: Also the name "holder" makes me believe that the content displayed, is not in this file.

Comment: You won't get anything without all of the params it passes along with the file.

Comment: So, what would be a solution for the problem?

Comment: Contact the publisher and request permission to obtain a local copy.